# Hovering over text not changing colour - libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, libgdx, hover

I am trying to change the colour of my font to white when I hover over it so that it is clear for the user to click that particular button to proceed. 
However, I am confused as to why it is not coming up as white and instead is staying as the colour it already is.
I'm using Hiero to get my font.

```
if (hovertext1.contains(tp.x, tp.y)) {
        font5.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            game.setScreen(new ChooseLevel(game));
            dispose();
        }
} else {
        font5.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

I'm just confused as to why it's not changing colour when I hover it?

Hovertext is a variable made using Rectangle.

tp - comes from:

```
Vector3 tp = new Vector3();
@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.unproject(tp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
    return false;
```

I've determined hovertext1 here;

```
hovertext1 = new Rectangle(330,255,125,50);
```

If I was to make it return true where would I do that?

Comment: Well, probably `hovertext1.contains(tp.x, tp.y)` returns `false`. What is `hovertext1`? What is `tp`, and how do you calculate `tp.x` and `tp.y`?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: And how `hovertext1` size and position are calculated? Did you check, does `hovertext1.contains(tp.x, tp.y)`ever return true?

Comment: I'm not sure where I would have it returning true or false - I haven't got it as a Boolean?

Comment: `hovertext1.contains(tp.x, tp.y)` method returns `boolean`. It's possible, that it always returns `false`, which means that `font5.setColor(Color.WHITE);` is never called.

Comment: Could you add to the question, how `hovertext1` size and position are calculated? Also, did you set your application's `InputProcessor` via `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(...);` ?

Comment: `hovertext1` should cover exactly the area, occupied by the text you draw with your `font5`. `hovertext1.contains(tp.x, tp.y)` will return true, if a point {tp.x, tp.y} is within `hovertext1`.

Comment: Anyway, it would probably be easier for you to use 'Scene2D' library. Create `Stage`, set it as input processor, add `Label` to it, and add `InputListener` to the label, overriding 'enter()' and 'exit()' methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think using `Scene2D` library would be convenient for your task. Just to show, what I mean - here is very simple example, of how to do what you ask:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;

    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage();

        stage = new Stage();
        final Label label = new Label("TEST", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        label.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2);
        label.addListener(
                new InputListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                        label.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
                        label.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
        );
        stage.addActor(label);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

}
```

Learn more about `Scene2D`: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d